# iphone OS 3.1.3 requires snow leopard upgrade

Tags: macos, iphone-sdk-3.0

itunes asked me to upgrade my iphone's OS to 3.1.3, so I complied naively.

then xcode told me that the latest iphone OS version it could support was 3.1.2.  So I went to download a new version from https://developer.apple.com/iphone/index.action#downloads, xcode 3.2.2 with iphone SDK.

but when i went to install that, i was told I needed snow leopard 10.6.2 or later.  so I'm just making sure that I am not misinterpreting anything when I say that, given that it is impossible to downgrade iphone OS versions without jailbreaking, I need to install a new version of the OS just so I can resume testing apps on my iphone?

Comment: Unless there's a good technical reason not to, I'd definitely upgrade to Snow Leopard.  We are up to 10.6.3, so I think the bugs have been more or less worked out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> given that it is impossible to
>   downgrade iphone OS versions without
>   jailbreaking

I'm not sure that's correct. I've done it before on ipods. If you go to ~/Library/iTunes, there's a few folders in there. Look through the folders for files with an "ipsw" file extension. These are the software upgrades. When you perform an upgrade, the upgrade file is saved here. So find the one you want to "downgrade" to. If you can't find it you may be able to google for it. In any case find the appropriate file. Then in iTunes if you option-click "Check for Update" it asks you to choose the file you want to use to perform the update instead of running the update check normally... so just select the ipsw file. That should "downgrade" you... I think. As I mentioned I did it a few years ago on an ipod.

Comment: right...but Apple no longer supports downgrades as discussed in http://www.tuaw.com/2010/02/09/tuaw-how-to-downgrading-your-3-1-3-iphone-to-3-1-2/.  I checked my ~/Library/iTunes/iPhone Software Upgrades folder and only 3.1.3 is in there.

More importantly, I can get the ipsw file from google, but when I downgrade it tells me the baseband won't get downgraded, and then it  sits there like a brick until I unplug + replug and allow it to upgrade me again to 3.1.3.  Again, I know there are ways to jailbreak it to make it work, but I don't want to as this is my work phone :)